# Dell Recovery Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dell, recovery-mode

My laptop was out of battery when it was sleep. And when i turn my laptop on again, my laptop was showing grub. Well, I just exit it and then show this [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6HiK.jpg). I just choose the second option (When it appears i think that it just recovery mode because of the laptop forcely off  (the battery empty). But when it becomes like new installing ubuntu. After it finished, my laptop user was lost, my data was lost and everything lost. Is there any solution so I can get my data back? because it's very important to me.

thank you.

Comment: "because it's very important to me." so restore the backup you have? If you do not have one please do not insult your data by calling it "important".

Answer (score 0):

`extundelete` will scan inodes looking for references to files that can be recovered.
since ubuntu was reinstalled there will be a lot of them besides your data,
and limiting search to /home may not find your data.